# Вывод string структуры list

Tags: c++, std-list

Доброго времени суток!
Существует следующая структура

```
struct Book
{
string name;
string fio;
string year;
string count;
};
```

Существует вот такой лист этой структуры:

```
list<Book> myList;
list<Book>::iterator myItt;
```

Заполнение структуры происходит следующим образом:

```
void CreateBook(Book &item, list<Book> &itemList)
{
cout << "Введите название книги: ";
cin >> item.name;
cout << "Введите фамилию автора: ";
cin >> item.fio;
cout << "Введите год издания: ";
cin >> item.year;
cout << "Введите кол-во книг: ";
cin >> item.count;

itemList.push_back(item);
}
```

Вопрос: Как можно вывести структуру на экран?

Мои попытки:

```
for ( auto myItt = myList.begin(); myItt != Mylist.end(); ++myItt  )
{
  cout << myItt->fio << endl; //ошибок, но ничего и не выводит
}
```

Полный код проекта: http://pastebin.com/d9M3KTu9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще-то все нормально выводит. Дописал вот так -

```
    case 1:
        cout << "Создаем новую книгу..." << endl;
        CreateBook(myBook, myList);

        for ( auto myItt = myList.begin(); myItt != myList.end(); ++myItt  )
        {
            cout << myItt->fio << endl; //ошибок, но ничего и не выводит
        }
```

и после ввода новой книги выводятся авторы из списка.
Надеюсь, вы понимаете, что и автор, и название в вашей программе обязаны быть **одним словом**?

**Update** Это тоже работает:

```
    case 3:
    {
        cout << "Сортируем по фамилии автора..." << endl;
        myList.sort(mySortfunction);

        for ( auto myItt = myList.begin(); myItt != myList.end(); ++myItt  )
        {
            cout << myItt->fio << endl; //ошибок, но ничего и не выводит
        }

        break;
    }
```

Comment: И действительно выводит. В case 3 есть функция сортировки, после нее такой вывод не работает. Значит причина в сортировке?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: После перезагрузки Visual Studio все действительно начало выполнятся. Иллюминати. Благодарю за потраченное время @harry